# How does numpy reshape works?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have data in a numpy array:

```
a = np.arange(100)
a = a.reshape((20,5))
```

When I type

```
a[:10]
```

it returns

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
       [35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
       [45, 46, 47, 48, 49]])
```

Now i decided to reshape the array into 3d array.

```
b = a.reshape((5,4,5))

array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
    [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
    [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
    [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],

   [[20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
    [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
    [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
    [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]],

   [[40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
    [45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
    [50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
    [55, 56, 57, 58, 59]],

   [[60, 61, 62, 63, 64],
    [65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
    [70, 71, 72, 73, 74],
    [75, 76, 77, 78, 79]],

   [[80, 81, 82, 83, 84],
    [85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
    [90, 91, 92, 93, 94],
    [95, 96, 97, 98, 99]]])
```

How do I slice b to that I obtain the values like a[:10]?
I tried

```
b[:10,0,:5]
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
       [60, 61, 62, 63, 64],
       [70, 71, 72, 73, 74],
       [80, 81, 82, 83, 84],
       [90, 91, 92, 93, 94]])
```

But its not correct.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You want a matrix with 10 rows with numbers from 0 to 50? but that's what reshape is for... b.reshape((20,5))[:10]

Comment: Are you sure `b` looks like this? I get something different ... I think you have instead `b = a.reshape(10,2,5)`

Comment: `b` looks like a `(10,2,5)` reshape

Comment: Try `b[:,:2,:]`; but I'll have get on my commputer w/ numpy to be sure.  There is some confusion ax to what you want.

Comment: sorry I've edited the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you use `b = a.reshape((5,4,5))` you just create a different view on the same data used by the array `a`. (ie changes to the elements of `a` will appear in `b`). `reshape()` does not copy data in this case, so it is a very fast operation. Slicing `b` and slicing `a` accesses the same memory, so there shouldn't be any need for a different syntax for the `b` array (just use `a[:10]`). If you *have* created a copy of the data, perhaps with `np.resize()`, and discarded `a`, just reshape `b`: `b.reshape((20,5))[:10]`.

Comment: Is there no way to slice b in  order to get a[:10]?

Comment: Your `b` array is divided into 5 blocks of 4-row, 5-columns each. You want all entries from the first 2 blocks and the first 2 rows from the third. I don't think there's a simple way to slice this to get a single 10x5 array without reshaping. In a sense, reshaping just changes the way you index the memory, so for your case it's an extra tool for slicing the way you want. It isn't slow.

Answer (score 3):

By reshaping `(20,5)` to `(5,4,5)`, there's no way you can pull out the 1st half of the values.  You can't split those `5` rows into 2 even groups:

```
In [9]: b[:2]
Out[9]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],

       [[20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]]])

In [10]: b[:3]
Out[10]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]],

       [[20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
        [35, 36, 37, 38, 39]],

       [[40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
        [45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
        [50, 51, 52, 53, 54],
        [55, 56, 57, 58, 59]]])
```

The last row of `a[:10]` is in the middle of `b[3,:,:]`.

Note that `b[:2]` is `(2,4,5)`, 8 rows of `a`, grouped into 2 sets of 4.

Now if you'd done `c=a.reshape(4,5,5)`, then `c[:2]` would have those same 10 rows - in 2 sets of 5.  And `c[:2].reshape(10,-1)` will look just like `a[:10]`.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a programmatic way to get what you want, but not a python slice.

It is important to understand what every component in the shape tells us about the arrangement. I like to think in terms of vectors.

Let's talk about the shape `(20, 5)` - this would mean, I have 20 vectors where every vector has 5 elements.

For the shape `(5, 4, 5)` - this would mean, I have 5 vectors, where each vector again has 4 vectors where every vector within has 5 elements.

This might sound complicated but with some deliberation, this could be understood.

Coming to your question, by `a[:10]` you want to retrieve the first 10 rows where each row should be a vector containing 5 elements but using a shape of `(5, 4, 5)`.
This is only possible if you retrieve the first 4 vectors from 1st vector of the leftmost dimension (5), next 4 vectors from the next vector and next 2 from the 3rd.

Python slicing might not be the best tool to achieve this.