# How can i reshape below numpy.ndarray into given shape?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, reshape, numpy-ndarray

I have an array X_train_mask of shape : (12600, ). Each of its sub-arrays have shape : (17640, ). I want X_train_mask to be of shape : (12600, 17640). How can i do that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some sample array with minimum length e.g:10 or 20 as possible?

Comment: I have added a picture. Please check it out.

Comment: Try using `reshape(1,-1)`

Comment: No. That will give a shape of (1, 12600).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does numpy reshape works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414706/how-does-numpy-reshape-works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i, X in enumerate(X_train_mask):
    X_train_mask[i] = list(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that there is an easier way to do that, but you can try:

```
X_train_mask = pd.concat([X_train_mask[i]
for i in range(len(X_train_mask )].T
```

Comment: Nope. That isn't working.